# Want to set Alarm even when App is closed and when mobile device is in sleep mood

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, background-service

I want to notify the user at a specific time using Alarm Manager. I have go through many answers and implemented but not working. The following code is working fine when App is running. It is not working when APP IN BACKGROUND & APP IS KILLED.
**Manifest file code**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<receiver
        android:name=".newAlarmBroadcast.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

**AlarmReceiver class**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Notification.createNotificationChannel(context);
    Notification.displayNotification(
            context, context.getString(R.string.alarm), "Its time to do your work",
            Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID
    );
```

**Notification Class**

```
public class Notification {

public static void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                context.getString(R.string.alarm_channel),
                importance
        );

        channel.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.channel_message));
        NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

public static void displayNotification(
        Context context,
        String title,
        String body,
        int id
) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotesMainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    manager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

**Here I am setting alarm time**

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private void setTheAlarm(long dateTime) {

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireActivity(), Constants.ALARM_ID, intent, 0);

    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime, pendingIntent);
    }
```

**Note**
Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID &
Constants.ALARM_ID both are same as required.

Answer (score 1):

Use WorkManager as it is easier, light-weight on the OS and backward compatible.

add to your dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
```

Create worker class:

```
class MyWorker(val appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {

       
 val notCompat =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(appContext.applicationContext)
 val channel = NotificationChannelCompat.Builder("com.yourcompany.noti_id", NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).setName("Importance").setName("Importance").setVibrationEnabled(true).build()

notCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel)

val noti = NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext.applicationContext, channel.id).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).setContentTitle("Internal Test").setContentText("Hope" + Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis).build()
          

/**
// If your are going to be doing long running operations. To avoid being killed by the //OS
setForegroundAsync(ForegroundInfo(channel.id.hashCode(), noti))
// .... Do long running operations here ....

**/

// Or If you are not doing long running operations....
NotificationManagerCompat.from(appContext.applicationContext).notify("organ".hashCode(), noti)
 
return Result.success()
}
```

add this to your manifest if you post as long running operations

```
 <service
    
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location|microphone"
            tools:node="merge" />
```

Possibly in a fore-ground service

```
 WorkManager.getInstance(this )
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("com.yourcompany.mywork", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(Constraints.NONE).build())
```

or If it is a one time work

```
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniqueWork("com.yourcompany.mywork", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>().setScheduleRequestedAt(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build())
```

See also:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running

Comment: Hi! @Abdullahi Thank you for your response, I've tried this, but this also works when the app is running. It is not working when app is in background or killed.

Comment: Okay, it may well depends on the device you are using. Some OEM employ aggressive sleep/dose mode, but it works on my device just fine. make sure you include the foreground service in your manifest if you are doing long running operations.

Comment: And also the work-manager may kill your work if the time-interval is too short on periodic work.

Comment: I am just triggering a notification at specific time. I am using Samsung-A037F Android 11

Comment: I am using periodic work with time interval of 1 minute ahead.

Comment: use the PeriodicWorkRequest instead of the OneTimeWorkRequest.

Comment: increase the time to 10 minutes and see.

Comment: 1 minute is too short to be posting notifications.

Comment: Still not working, this time I gave interval of 15 minutes. I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: you can enqueue the worker in a foreground service.